# Count document MongoDB java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I am new to MongoDB and I am finding rather complicated to count the child number of my nested documents.

This is part of my `'users'` collection.

```
"_id" : ObjectId("58f9f7a91fb2bf7c46abe5d6"),
"name" : "fernando guima",
"premium" : true,
"email" : "lolol@loladamix.com",
"creationDate" : ISODate("2017-04-21T12:14:33.970Z"),
"playlists" : [
    {
        "name" : "minha Playlist",
        "creationDate" : ISODate("2017-04-21T12:14:33.982Z"),
        "videos" : [
            {
                "video_id" : "video1",
                "creationDate" : ISODate("2017-04-21T13:00:38.461Z")
            },
            {
                "video_id" : "video2",
                "creationDate" : ISODate("2017-04-21T13:00:38.502Z")
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name" : "minha Playlist 2",
        "creationDate" : ISODate("2017-04-21T12:14:33.983Z"),
        "videos" : [ ]
    }
]
```

}

I want to be able to retrieve the number of 'videos' in my 'playlist' (playlist childs) and retrieve a video data, how can I do that?

I wrote the following code that adds a `video` to a given `playlist`:

```
public void addToPlaylist(String parameter, String value, String playListName, String video_id){
    //user document
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject(parameter, value);
    //First it fetches the wanted document by a parameter and its value e.g, (name, Fernando)
    BasicDBObject mObject = new BasicDBObject();
    mObject.put("video_id", video_id);
    mObject.put("creationDate", new Date());

    BasicDBObject updateObj = new BasicDBObject();
    //falta percorrer o array das playlists para encontrar o id pelo nome da playlist
    updateObj.put("$push", new BasicDBObject("playlists."+"0"+".videos", mObject));

    mMongo.getCollection("users").updateOne(query, updateObj);
}
```

I expect to receive, `{videos : 2}` as the number of videos in my first playlist. And some output about video data like: `{"video_id" : "video1"}`

Regards

Comment: Can you add the expected json response to the post ?

Comment: Updated, hope it's clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below query. The query will `$match` to select the document followed by `$unwind` of `playlists` array and `$project` to reach `videos` array to calculate its `$size` and extract `video_id`.

```
 MongoClient client = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
 MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase("db");
 MongoCollection<Document> collection = database
                .getCollection("collection");

 Bson filter = Filters.eq("_id", new ObjectId("58f9f7a91fb2bf7c46abe5d6"));

 List<VideoResult> results = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(Aggregates.match(filter), Aggregates.unwind("$playlists"), Aggregates.project(Projections.fields(Arrays.asList(Projections.computed("videos", new Document("$size","$playlists.videos")),
                Projections.computed("video_ids", "$playlists.videos.video_id")))))).map(VideoResult::new).into(new ArrayList<>());
```

Output:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("58f9f7a91fb2bf7c46abe5d6"),
        "videos" : 2,
        "video_ids" : [
                "video1",
                "video2"
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("58f9f7a91fb2bf7c46abe5d6"),
        "videos" : 0,
        "video_ids" : [ ]
}
```

Pojo:

```
public class VideoResult {

    private int videos;
    private List<String> videoIds;

    public VideoResult(Document doc) {
        this.videos = doc.getInteger("videos");
        this.videoIds = (List<String>) doc.get("video_ids");
    }
  // getters and setters 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
Any sugestion on how I can parse the output?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, MongoDB 3.4

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {$unwind: '$playlists'}, {$addFields: {'playlists.id': '$_id'}},        
    {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: '$playlists'}},
    {$unwind: {path: '$videos', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},
    {$group: {_id: {name: '$name', creationDate: '$creationDate', _id: '$id'},
             video_ids: {$push: '$videos.video_id'}, 
             videos: {$sum: {$cond: [{$ifNull: ['$videos', 0]}, 1, 0]}}}},
    {$addFields: {_id: '$_id._id'}}])
```

Output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58f9f7a91fb2bf7c46abe5d6"),
    "video_ids" : [ ],
    "videos" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58f9f7a91fb2bf7c46abe5d6"),
    "video_ids" : [
        "video1",
        "video2"
    ],
    "videos" : 2
}
```